# Make error on Twist.msg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After editing my CMakeList and running a make on my package and I received an error I'm not sure how to fix.  The error is:

roslib.msgs.MsgSpecException: Twist.msg: Duplicate field names in message: ['linear', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'angular', 'x', 'y', 'z']
make[3]: *** [../msg_gen/cpp/include/movbotGPS/Twist.h] Error 1

I'v checked my Twist.msg file and I believe it's setup correctly:

Vector3 linear
float64 x
float64 y
float64 z
Vector3 angular
float64 x
float64 y
float64 z

So I don't understand why I'm getting an error in "Duplicate field names in message".  Can anyone explain?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12912/make-error-on-twist.msg/) by [GenePSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1562/genepsmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you creating your own copy of the Twist message?

You should declare a dependency on geometry_msgs and use the Twist message there.

**EDIT:**

You can add a dependency on geometry_msgs by adding a line like this to your manifest.xml:

```
<depend package="geometry_msgs"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2